# Value cannot be null or empty - ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have these fields in my View :

```
<dd>
    <a href="~/Docs/@Url.Content(Model.DocPath)">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.DocPath)</a>
</dd>
<dd>
    <a href="~/Fonts/@Url.Content(Model.FontPath)">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.FontPath)</a>
</dd>
```

When I upload something for Doc, but not for Font, then I open this View, I get Value cannot be null or empty error for this line :

```
<a href="~/Docs/@Url.Content(Model.DocPath)">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.DocPath)</a>
```

Why am I getting the error for this line? This line is not null. And How can I make that View visible when the second url line is null? Thanks.

Comment: Wrap them in an `if` statement that test for `null` - `@if (Model.FontPath != null) { <a href=.....` etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes as @Stephen Muecke said write an if else

```
if(Model.DocPath != null)
{
    <a href="~/Fonts/@Url.Content(Model.FontPath)">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.FontPath)</a>   
}
else
{
<a href="~/Docs/@Url.Content(Model.DocPath)">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.DocPath)</a>  
}
```